# What is the effect of adding `@RequestScoped` to a method in Quarkus?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, scope, cdi, quarkus

I have a Quarkus project which uses JDBI (and Kotlin,) and implements a DAOUtils class for producing its various DAOs.

```
@ApplicationScoped
class DAOUtils(
  @DataSource("user") userDataSource: AgroalDatSource
) {
  private val userJDdbi = Jdbi.create(userDataSource)
  // more jdbi configuration here

  @RequestScoped
  fun userDAO(): UserDAO {
    return userJdbi.onDemand(UserDAO::class.java)
  }
}
```

```
interface UserDAO {
  @SQLQuery("""
    SELECT *
    FROM user
    WHERE id = :id
  """
  )
  fun findUser(
    @Bind("id") id: Long
  ): User
}
```

The UserDao class is then invoked by:

```
class UserService(
  userDao: UserDAO
) {
  fun findUser(id: Long) {
    return userDao.findUser(id)
  }
}
```

The intent here is to produce a `UserDAO` object whose lifecycle is tied to the request, however all of my instincts and training tell me that the `DAOUtils` methods should be annotated with `@Produces` as mentioned [here](https://marcelkliemannel.com/articles/2021/overview-of-bean-scopes-in-quarkus/#dynamically-scoped).

The above code compiles and I can get data back, but part of me thinks that the implementation is incorrect (or at least sub-optimal), although the other part of me wonders if it is actually OK and part of some optimization similar to how we can omit `@Inject` with constructors.  Is the current implementation correct, or do I also need `@Produces`, and how can I verify the beans are being created and destroyed correctly?

Comment: `@RequestScoped` on a method only makes sense when used with `@Produces`

Comment: You don't need the `@Produces` annotation, a scope annotation on a bean method is enough to declare a producer method in Quarkus. That's indeed an improvement on top of the specification, as described here: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#simplified-producer-method-declaration